# Mac login screen shows 'other..' user, possible malware?

Tags: macos, login-screen

I was cleaning my mac files in the /libraries/launchdaemons & /launchagents folder with suspicious files. After restarting my mac the "other..." user appeared. My root user is already disabled, does this mean someone is hacking into my mac? If so, how can I fix this?

P.S. I have already deleted recent applications from my mac that may have caused this.

Comment: Have you checked System Preferences > User accounts ? @user373969

Comment: This is normal.  the “other” selection allows you to enter a different username

Comment: @Allan It is an unknown user that I never added and don't know the password to login in to it. I ran a malware scan and it is still there.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?